# Using button click to open helpProvider c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Just a quick question but is it possible to open a helpProvider?

All I want is open a CHM help file when I click a button in addition to the F1 key?

If it’s not possibly anyone know of a work around?

Thanks Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a Windows Forms Application.

There is a Windows Forms Control called HelpProvider that does it for you.

```
System.Windows.Forms.HelpProvider hlpProvider = new System.Windows.Forms.HelpProvider();
hlpProvider.SetShowHelp(this, true);
// Help file
hlpProvider.HelpNamespace = "helpFile.chm";
```

You can open your help file with

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "helpFile.cfm";
proc.Start();
```

Comment: sorry yup my mistake.
but doesnt answer my question

Comment: i add another option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            helpProvider1.HelpNamespace = Application.StartupPath + "\\filename.chm";
            helpProvider1.SetShowHelp(this, true);
       }

private void HelpText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Help.ShowHelp(this, helpProvider1.HelpNamespace);

        }
```

**Good luck ^_^**